# How to Spiderfy all the markerClusters in Leaflet markerClusters map library

Tags: leaflet, maps, leaflet.markercluster, angular-leaflet-directive

I am using Leaflet masterCluster in angular for maps. I have added some markers in the map and i can see the marker clusters in the map. Currently i am able to spiderfy when i click on the marker cluster.
My requirement is to make all clusters automatically "spiderfy" when i load the map.

Here i am sharing stackblitz link to play around
Link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ts-leaflet-markercluster-hufa4u?file=locations.json

Comment: Posted directly on the relevant Leaflet.markercluster repo issues https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/744#issuecomment-1091468297

Comment: Commented on the existing open issue on github as well. https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/744.